# JS minification - Configure Google closure compiler options for Play! 2.2

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, bundling-and-minification, minify, playframework-2.2

There is a requirement to minify our Javascript and CSS for production. We are aware that this is supported out of the box with Play!. The issue we currently have in our project is that the JS is being minified aggressively. Is there a way to change the options in our Build to use the simple optimisation options?

The original code looks like this

```
var MYNAMESPACE = MYNAMESPACE || {};

MYNAMESPACE._toggleDefaultOptions = function($form, $options, bool) {
if( bool ) {
    $options.prop( "checked", true ).parents( 'li' ).addClass( 'visuallyhidden' );
    $form.find( '#co2Figure' ).val( '' )
        .end().find( '#co2NoFigure' ).prop( "checked", false );
} else {
       //check if electric has data flagged if true turn it off and reset everything
       if( typeof $form.data( "electricFlagged" ) !== 'undefined' ) {
         $options.prop( "checked", false ).parents( 'li' ).removeClass( 'visuallyhidden'   );
         //remove the electric data

       }
 }
}
$(function(){
    var $form = $("#form")
    $options = $form.find("select");
    MYNAMESPACE._toggleDefaultOptions($form, $options, false);
});
```

The resulting Minification

```
var module$application={};var MYNAMESPACE$$module$application=MYNAMESPACE$$module$application||{};MYNAMESPACE$$module$application._toggleDefaultOptions=function($form,$options,bool){if(bool){$options.prop("checked",true).parents("li").addClass("visuallyhidden");$form.find("#co2Figure").val("").end().find("#co2NoFigure").prop("checked",false)}else if(typeof $form.data("electricFlagged")!=="undefined")$options.prop("checked",false).parents("li").removeClass("visuallyhidden")};
$(function(){var $form=$("#form");$options=$form.find("select");MYNAMESPACE$$module$application._toggleDefaultOptions($form,$options,false)});
```

Comment: That renaming output makes me think that the `debug` flag is getting set for closure-compiler.